# recycler-view inside recycler-view vertical scrolling not working

Tags: android, scrollview, android-recyclerview

Recycler View inside another Recycler View Both vertical scroll
inside recycler view scroll not working

[image]
    RecyclerView rvItem = findViewById(R.id.rv_item);
            NestedScrollView nestedScrollView = findViewById(R.id.nestedScroll);
            rvItem.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
            ItemAdapter itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(buildItemList(),nestedScrollView);
            rvItem.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
            rvItem.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

in side ItemAdapter:-

```
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(itemViewHolder.rvSubItem.getContext(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,
                    false);
            SubItemAdapter subItemAdapter = new SubItemAdapter(item.getSubItemList());
            itemViewHolder.rvSubItem.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            itemViewHolder.rvSubItem.setAdapter(subItemAdapte

r);
```

Child xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#f3f3f3"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="12dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="12dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_item_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="12sp"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="Item Title"/>
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_sub_item"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="400dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Put your recyclerviews inside nestedscrollview and disable nested scrolling

Comment: [use this tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/mastering-complex-lists-with-the-android-recyclerview/)

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: @kam1234 Please check above code

Comment: post your main xml

Comment: <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/nestedScroll"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>